# How to implement functions that work on turtle graphics in C?

Tags: c, function, turtle-graphics, function-call

So i've been trying to get this function to draw a red box using turtle graphics but it seems like the function is being ignored. Here is my code:

```
int main(int agrc, char*argc[])
{
   create_turtle_world();
   void draw_red();
   return (p1world_shutdown());


}

void draw_red()
{
   pen_colour(RED);
   forward(150);
   turn(90);
   forward(50);
   turn(90);
   forward(150)
   turn(90);
   forward(50);
   turn(90);
   turn(-90);
}
```

I don't know what I did wrong here, it's compiled correctly, just not drawing a box.

Comment: This would be a better question if it included header files and ... I've never heard of this library, so a link would be cool if you have one.

Answer (score 2):

In `main()`, instead of

```
void draw_red();    //function declaration
```

you've to use

```
draw_red();         //function call
```